# Computing best-fit polygon from shape given number of target sides (or edges)

Tags: polygon

I have an arbitrary shape, drawn by the user on a canvas, and I would like to compute the best-fit polygon from that shape given the number of sides or edges the output polygon should have. Specifically, I would like a function with the following signature:

```
polygon computePolygon(Shape shape, int numberOfSides)
 {
  ...
  return polygon; // return polygon with numberOfSides sides
 }
```

For instance, let's say I want to obtain a quadrilateral from the shape drawn by the user (say a GeneralPath), then I would input computePolygon(generalPath, 4).

How would I go about this ?

Answer (score 1):

[This paper may help you.](http://www.scribd.com/doc/396645/A-Hybrid-Genetic-Algorithm-For-Two-Types-Of-Polygonal-Approximation-Problems)

Reference:  A Hybrid Genetic Algorithm for Two Types of Polygonal Approximation Problems,  Bin Wang and Chaojian Shi

Comment: Thanks for that. I see that this problem is referred to as the "min-ε problem" or the "minimum-distortion problem" in polygonal approximation. The proposed algorithms in the scientific literature seem quite complex, though. I'm looking for something easy to implement, if possible. It doesn't have to be optimal.